# XSL Join a list of elements’s value with comma ',' separator

Tags: xml, xslt

Input xml, I have xml which contain the below format, i need to display the details as name sae,dadd in the outpout

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Employeedetails>
    <Employee>
       <Name>sae</Name>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
       <Name>Dadd</Name>
  </Employee>
 </Employeedetails>
```

XSL:

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customer>
       <NameDetaisl>sae,Dadd,</NameDetaisl>
</Customer>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using xslt-1.0 (because of for-each to concat the Names). You can use `position()` to avoid separator at the end of a list.

Try to change your for-each as follow:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/Employeedetails/Employee">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1" >
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Which will generate:

```
 <NameDetaisl>sae, Dadd</NameDetaisl>
```